# How to prevent the automatic client side validations execution in a ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm using a ModalPopupExtender to show a modal popup window with a bunch of input controls and a couple of validators with EnableClientScript set to true.
The issue I'm facing is, that the client-side validations get executed right after the modal popup is shown (via client-side code, not from server).
Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently facing the exact same problem than you.

For the moment, I've did some JavaScript to handle this situation by filling the current input with a "Default" text value. I also modify the style color when the Default value is in the input to gray color instead of black.

Then when the user click in the input, another JavaScript function is called to clear it and change the color back to Black!

So my Javascript validation are based on my input color style. I don't very like the way I'm doing this because the validator should work...

I found some informations about that there : 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1066821.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1057570.aspx

But actually when I'm inserting their tagMapping in my web.config, all my control in my Master page or .apsx page cannot be found in my .apsx.vb page...

P.S. If you want me to give you my current Javascript (working perfectly) just tell me :)